# Why pivottable.js not working in Meteor project?

Tags: jquery, dom, meteor, pivottable.js

pivottable.js works like a charm, but not in the most basic meteor project.
Having html:

```
<body>
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

js (attendance var is defined and everything works in non meteor project):

```
$('#output').pivot(attendance,
  {
    rows: ["group", "trainer", "client"],
    cols: ["came"]
  }
);
```

In Meteor project pivot.js is placed in client/compatibility folder as it should and load order is right: jquery > pivot.js > my js code. Getting error:

```
pivot.js:949

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasChildNodes' of undefined
$.fn.pivot @ pivot.js:949
(anonymous function) @ sandbox.js:20
(anonymous function) @ sandbox.js?64df4e0c48aa567cada8bd4c28bd682ed2d9ab36:41
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor templates are working a bit differently. When it runs, the DOM is not rendered yet. In order to achieve that, you have to load any external libs that are relying on DOM inside a template in that template rendered callback. In this case:

```
Template.body.rendered = function() {
$('#output').pivot(attendance,
  {
    rows: ["group", "trainer", "client"],
    cols: ["came"]
  }
);
}
```